# What's the difference between Hidden layer and fully connected layer?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow

I'm newer in the Deep learning domain,

I would like to know what's the difference between a hidden layer and a fully connected layer? 
Are they the same thing?
If no, How to create a hidden layer with Tensorflow?

Comment: Your last question is off topic here, as it is about code. I suggest removing that question to avoid your question being closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A hidden layer is any layer that's not an input or an output. Suppose you're classifying images. The image is the input. The predicted class is the output. Any layers in between input and output layers are hidden.

One type of layer is a fully-connected layer. Fully-connected layers have weights connected to all of the outputs of the previous layer.

A layer can be

- hidden but not fully-connected (e.g. a hidden convolutional layer), or
- fully connected but not hidden (e.g. a fully connected output layer), or
- hidden and fully-connected (a standard choice), or
- neither hidden nor fully connected (e.g. a deconvolution output layer)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, If I understand what you say, The convolution layer and the pooling layer are hidden layers because they are between the input layer and the output layer.